Why don't we ever hear about potassium pollution from fertilizer runoff?
News articles are constantly droning on about algael blooms, dead zones and such from excessive agricultural NPK fertilizer usage...
Yet, we never hear of excessive potassium causing a problem...
Why?
Do algae, seagrasses and other aquatic flora that might explode in numbers simply not need potassium?  And they are (apparently) not harmed by it either?

Potassium is in abundance wrt phosphorus, which is the limiting nutrient.

Moreover, most of the potassium do gets absorbed by the plants or the soil. See: https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/earth-and-planetary-sciences/potassium-fertiliser. Even if there is a runoff, most of it will be either nitrogen or phosphorus.

It's a great question. Obviously it matters. K is a potential limiting plant macronutrient, otherwise it wouldn't be included in NPK. And like all good things, too much is bad.

That's a good question, particularly because potassium is seldom discussed negatively. The main reason is that overabundance of potassium is relatively innocuous compared to nitrogen and phosphorus. In other words, the chemistry of N & P richer than simple alkali metal ion. Nature is quite tolerant of alkali metal ions. For example, seawater contains about 0.5 M NaCl, which is a significant amount of salt and $\ce{Na+}$. Seawater also contains around 400 mg/L of $\ce{K+}$. Potassium is already abundant in aqueous and land plants. Recall the element name derives from pot-ash, a substance obtained by extracting the ash left after burning wood in pots. Although, it is an essential nutrient for plants, but unlike nitrogen and phosphorus, it does not cause overgrowth when present in excess.
Unlike nitrogen and phosphorus-containing anions, potassium ions are inert and do not alter pH on their own. Moreover, potassium does not exist in multiple oxidation states like nitrogen and phosphorus. It does not form precipitates or chelates with other essential elements. The reason nitrogen and phosphorus are often in the news is due to their interesting chemical behavior and their ability to do more harm than an innocent K ion if they are blindly used. These two elements can exist in multiple forms in nature, ranging from relatively safe compounds to highly dangerous like nitrogen oxides that pollute the environment. Phosphate ions, besides causing overgrowth of plants, also bind strongly to soluble iron and magnesium, forming precipitates. Both iron and magnesium are essential for higher life forms. Additionally, phosphate ions can alter aqueous pH and have a buffering capacity.
Note that NPK fertilizers are not bad, it is the overuse. If fertilizers did not exist, most of people would be suffering from famine. I heard in a talk (> 10 year ago) that every third nitrogen atom in our body comes from a nitrogen fertilizer.

Just to add fine points to the existing answer, quoting Ref 1:

Potassium (K) outputs comprise removals in harvested crops and losses via a number of pathways. No specific environmental issues arise from K losses to the wider environment, and so they have received little attention. Nevertheless, K is very soluble and so can be leached to depth or to surface waters. Also, because K is bound to clays and organic materials, and adsorbed K is mostly associated with fine soil particles, it can be eroded with particulate material in runoff water and by strong winds. It can also be lost when crop residues are burned in the open. Losses represent a potential economic cost to farmers and reduce soil nutritional status for plant growth.

As an essential macronutrient there can be a supply gap between the extractable K in the soil and what is optimal for plant yield. Much K is bound in clays and soluble K may be lost in runoff or groundwater. However, any excess salt can cause problems (Ref 2):

Salts are composed of positively charged ions (cations) and negatively charged ions (anions). They can be dissolved in water (soluble salts) or be present as solids. Salts in soil can originate from soil parent material; from irrigation water; or from fertilizers, manures, composts or other amendments. The predominant salts that accumulate in soils are calcium, magnesium, sodium, potassium, sulfate, chloride, carbonate and bicarbonate. Any salt that accumulates in excess amounts in soil can cause plant growth problems.
Salts in the root zone can reduce crop yield by making it difficult for roots to extract water from the soil.
Excess sodium causes problems related to soil structure. As sodium percentage increases, so does the risk of dispersion of soil aggregates (Figures 1 and 2).
High concentrations of certain salts in the soil may also be toxic to plants (see “Beyond salt and sodium: Specific ion toxicities”).

References
(1) Goulding, K. et al. (2021). Outputs: Potassium Losses from Agricultural Systems. In: Murrell, T.S., Mikkelsen, R.L., Sulewski, G., Norton, R., Thompson, M.L. (eds) Improving Potassium Recommendations for Agricultural Crops. Springer, Cham. https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-030-59197-7_3
(2) María Isabel Zamora Re, Abigail Tomasek, Bryan G. Hopkins, Dan M. Sullivan and Linda Brewer (2022). Managing Salt-affected Soils for Crop Production. OSU Extension Catalog. PNW 601.
